# Set job for push notification in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to set job for push notification in laravel. Like if i click submit the function run once and my notification keep going in backgroud and my page don't keep loading.

Comment: use ajax for that

Comment: I wanna do it from laravel only.

Comment: what have done till now in this case